# Autoplay HTML5 video with Fancybox3

Tags: html, video, fancybox

I want to autoplay an HTML5 video after opening it on fancybox3.

here's my codepen:
https://codepen.io/ableslayer/pen/aygGQX

and my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
      afterShow: function() {
        // After the show-slide-animation has ended - play the vide in the current slide
        this.content.find('video').trigger('play')

        // Attach the ended callback to trigger the fancybox.next() once the video has ended.
        this.content.find('video').on('ended', function() {
          $.fancybox.next();
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your video a id (myVideo) and add this line in afterShow function

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
 vid.play();
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
      afterShow: function() {
        // After the show-slide-animation has ended - play the vide in the current slide
       var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
       vid.play(); 

        // Attach the ended callback to trigger the fancybox.next() once the video has ended.
        this.content.find('video').on('ended', function() {
          $.fancybox.next();
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<a data-fancybox data-src="#one" class="fancybox">link</a>
<div id="one" style="display:none">
  <video id='myVideo' width="400" controls autoplay>
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">          
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. But what if I have multiple videos in one page? Can I change it to getElementByClass?

Comment: Yes. then loop over and call play